# Which website has the complete sector/industry info of a stock?

Tags: equities

https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/XFLT/profile

For example, I don't see the sector/industry info the above stock. Is there a website that has complete sector/industry info for all stocks (at the least the ones on the US market)?

Comment: XFLT is a closed-end fund, so you could say the sector is Finance, the industry is Closed End Funds.  But it is common for this kind of non-operating company to be listed without sector and industry. XFLT is an investment vehicle, rather than a company providing a product or service.

Comment: Thanks. How do you find the info that it is a closed-end fund?